# Managing big amount of data in iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, ipad, core-data

I am going to use Core Data and SQLite together for managing big amount of data on iOS devices. Is that good solution? Are there other ways?

Comment: How big ? If you are using core-data then why you need sqlite ?

Comment: Please ask a question about a specific problem, rather than ask people to recommend things. Try using google to find what other people have done.

Comment: You should use either core data or sqlite! it will be easier for you to manage operations!

Comment: I heard that core data can not handle a large amount of data properly. So, some developers prefer to use SQLite with FMDB for this. But what if I use data core just for managing and SQLite for storing the data?

Comment: core data use sqlite as root so if sqlite can handle then core data definitely will handle! Then also if you have doubt then use sqlite, it is fine! but why both?

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite can handle very large ammount of data. and core data also use sqlite in backend. SO your approach is right. You should go for this.
for more detail see this:
http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in which you can write data to file in iOS.

One is NSUserDefaults and the other is Core Data.

NSUserDefaults is not the proper way for storing large amounts of data. It's used to store application settings and temporary data.

Core Data is the proper way for storing and managing large ammounts of data.

Comment: There are other ways. `NSFileHandle`, for example. Or classes like `NSData` that can write themselves to files. Or others...